# WPF Calender Week

Tags: wpf, view, calendar

I'm new in here and at programming. I'm making a program that only shows one week at a time. I have some appointments spanning over several weeks, and my question is: Is there a way to only show the "appointments" of the week you are currently in?

Comment: Please share what you have tried already and where you got stuck. StackOverflow is for helping you, not doing the work for you. Also read [ask]

Comment: i have already searched on google and youtube after anything there came to my head there could have anything to do with my problem.

Comment: More like share what you have done programmatically, not googling or watching youtube videos.(Vis hvad du har foretaget dig programmeringsmæssigt)

Comment: Please post an [mcve] of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out

```
        var googleCal = new GoogleClass();

        var ugedag = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

        var getMondays = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(6));

        var getTuesdays = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));

        var getWednesday = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(4));

        var getThursday = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));

        var getFriday = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));

        var getSaturday = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

        var getSunday = googleCal.GoogleEvents.Where(e => e.StartDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(0));



            foreach (var googleCalGoogleEvent in googleCal.GoogleEvents)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(googleCalGoogleEvent.Title);
            }

        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {

            foreach (var events in getMondays)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getTuesdays)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getWednesday)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getThursday)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getFriday)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getSaturday)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }
        if (ugedag == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            foreach (var events in getSunday)
            {
                NewMethod(events);
            }
        }

    }

    private void NewMethod(GoogleEvents events)
    {
        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            Monday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            Tuesday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            Wednsday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            Thuesday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            Friday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            Saturday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }

        if (events.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            Sunday.Items.Add($"{events.Title} \n{events.StartDate:dd-MM HH:MM}-{events.EndDate:HH:MM}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far i have this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var googleCal = new GoogleClass();

        foreach (var googleEvent in googleCal.GoogleEvents)
        {
            if ((googleEvent.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek - googleEvent.StartDate.Value.DayOfWeek)  
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(googleEvent.Title + " " + googleEvent.StartDate);
            } 


        } 
    } 
} 


public class GoogleEvents
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } 
}

class GoogleClass
{
    public List<GoogleEvents> GoogleEvents = new List<GoogleEvents>();

    static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart"; 



    public GoogleClass()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

        }
        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                } 

                GoogleEvents.Add(new GoogleEvents {Title = eventItem.Summary, StartDate = eventItem.Start.DateTime});


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know why it wouldnt allow my public class in to the code

Comment: but that day og the week didnt work as i wanted it to